# Fiber bundle in smooth category and topological category

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $G$ be a Lie group. Denote by $Bun(M,G)$ the set of all equivalent smooth Principal bundles on $M$ with structural group $G$ in smooth category. And denote by $Bun(M,G)_{top}$ the set of all equivalent Principal bundles on $M$ with structural group $G$ in the topological category when $G$ is seen as a topological group. Then we have a natural map  $\varphi:Bun(M,G) \rightarrow Bun(M,G)_{top}$. Is $\varphi$ a bijection and how to prove it?

Comment: [Crossposted on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1239313/39599).

Comment: @IgorBelegradek the space $BG$ is not a manifold, right? What do you mean by a smooth map into it?

Comment: This should be true, at least if $G$ is compact, by the existence of approximations of $BG$ by finite dimensional smooth manifolds and smooth approximation of continuous functions.

Comment: By http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298873/

Comment: @skupers: your remark doesn't have any meaning unless you say which version of $BG$ you are using. $BG$ has many different (albeit homotopy equivalent) versions.

Comment: @JohnKlein: Thanks, I should have been more precise. I meant that there is a model of $BG$ such that there exist smooth manifolds $(BG)_i$ and maps $(BG)_i \to BG$ that are $i$-connected. One explicit construction of such $(BG)_i$ is given by embedding $G$ in some $O(n)$ (that is, finding a faithful orthogonal representation) and taking quotients of Stiefel manifolds.